# Find circles which the point in, according to each circle's relative radius?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

[image]
Hello I want find circles which the point in, according to each circle's relative radius.

I have some code and its work. But can anyone knows any more solutions? Since I have not yet figured out how to convert a polygon into a circle, and how to take the center of the polygon to display it on the map as a circle. :

```
exports.getRoomsNears = function (req, res) {
  log.info('get all rooms');
    var limit = req.params.limit || 10
    var coords = [];
    coords[0] = req.params.latitude;
    coords[1] = req.params.longitude;

    Room.find({
        location: {
            $geoIntersects: {
                $geometry: {
                    type: "Point",
                    coordinates: coords
                }
        }
    }}).limit(limit).exec(function (err, locations) {
        if (err) {
            return res.json(500, err);
        }
        log.info(locations);
        res.json(200, locations);
});};
```

and I have schema for my circle

```
var schema = new Schema ({

name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},

inPrivate: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: false
},

location: {
    type: { type: String, "enum": [
        "Point",
        "MultiPoint",
        "LineString",
        "MultiLineString",
        "Polygon",
        "MultiPolygon"
    ] },
    coordinates: { type: Array }
},

radius : Number,

created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
}});
```

There was another idea to be right , to issue a circle within a certain range , and then on the client to check whether the point intersects with the circle ?